# How to add jQuery CDN Link in .html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, visual-studio-code, cdn

Where should I add CDN Link in my Project? I have made a Project in Codepen, and over there It’s added in the Javascript column. But in my local machine do I have to add it in .html or .js? I have tried adding it in my `<head>` of .html but it’s not working.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried without "https:" and "//" as well. But still no luck.

Please let me know if I need to do anything else besides this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code locally, your HTML file should look like this:

```
<!DOCYTPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="url here"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

If that still does not work, you should put your code through the [W3 Validator](https://validator.w3.org/). You can view the errors with your HTML there.

Answer (score -1):

In Codepen you need to go to settings.
Then choose JS and there you can add external libraries.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the answers, Actually, I got the solution, I mistakenly added `js/main.js` instead of `<script src="main.js"></script>` .

And next thing I checked, I had added jQuery CDN Link in my .js file as well. I removed it from there and It worked.